# R.java error "; " expected

Tags: android, r.java-file

I have tried to compile my project and then this error suddenly occurred. What could be the cause of this? can anyone please help me? error occurred in R.java file

Comment: NEVER EVER touch R.Java. You are not supposed to.

Comment: I didnt. since it is an auto generated file, i dont understand how did it come out with a semicolon error

Comment: I highly doubt that R.Java isn't generated corrctly. However, simply delete it and rebuild the project after cleaning it. R.Java will be recreated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to clean and rebuild you project. The R.java file should be recreated. And if this does not work you can try to find the missing ;.
I hope that solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs due to change in layout. May be you have to add a string in it.

e.g. `android:layout_below="abc xyz ghi"`

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error, and it is definitely odd. I fixed it be renaming the ID's of several elements in my main activity layout. I had used hyphens in the names which resulted in this error. Changed them to underscores and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same error. Turns out that I have managed to enter ID value which included space into id field of a Button (and the IDE didn't protest). (Apparently I had clicked into bad field when trying to change text label.)